# Why is a Topological Field Theory equivalent to a Frobenius algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, mathematical-physics, topological-quantum-field-theory

How can a physicist understand a **2-dimensional topological field theory** as a **Frobenius algebra**? Are there some explicit examples in order to understand this relation?

The definition (e.g. on Wikipedia) of the Frobenius algebra is quite clear, it is a finite dimensional associative algebra equipped with a special non-degenerate bilinear form. If this algebra is represented by $n\times n$ matrices then the bilinear form is the trace.

Now, I fail to see how this is a TFT.

In specific two very famous topological field theories in 2-dimensions (that physicists work with a lot) are the topological A-model and the topological B-model (a la Witten). These model are related via mirror symmetry. How are they defined as a Frobenius algebra and what are their differences as a Frobenius algebra. And natural question to ask is wether mirror symmetry in the TFT side relates *somehow* the two Frobenius algebras on the algebra side.

So I would like to understand intuitively why a Frobenius algebra and a TFT are the same thing and the detail I ask in specific about the A-model and the B-model which are of my main interest.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256630/why-is-a-topological-field-theory-equivalent-to-a-frobenius-algebra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michael Atiyah has already written [an article](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/atiyahinttqft.pdf) that does this well. Here's the citation, should the link ever rot:

> Atiyah, Michael. "An introduction to topological quantum field theories." Turkish J. Math 21.1 (1997): 1-7.

There is also [this](http://mat.uab.es/~kock/TQFT/FS.pdf), the very first google hit in my search, that also appears to get the job done, but it seems to have more detail. It might be good to keep [the errata to the book that it comes from](http://mat.uab.es/~kock/TQFT.html) handy too.

Finally, here is [another article](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/TQFT/Terry'sREUPaperOnTQFT's.pdf) to use.

Comment: These articles seem nice but I assume the OP would like a (relatively) short answer in more physical terms. In physics a topological QFT is something very specific. I assume the "pants" operations can be considered in the shame fashion as string amplitudes in some sense but I cannot give a very precise formulation.